# chart_Series does not plot when called in function with condition that evaluates to FALSE

Tags: r, quantmod

I am begginer with R so maybe I am missing some concept about functions. But here is my example and I am interested why it works like that?

```
require(quantmod);

myPlot = function(ts, addAdx = TRUE) {
  chart_Series(ts);

  if (addAdx) {
    add_TA(ADX(HLC(ts))$ADX)  
  }

}

getSymbols("DIA", src='yahoo');
myPlot(DIA, addAdx = FALSE)
```

If I set addAdx parameter to false then my function does not plot the chart (otherwise its fine). Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't use return the R functions return the latest computed value.

If addAdx is set to FALSE the function returns a void.

This code solve your problem:

```
  myPlot = function(ts, addAdx = TRUE) {
  p <- chart_Series(ts);

  if (addAdx) {
   p <- add_TA(ADX(HLC(ts))$ADX)  
  }

  p #return(p)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens, but here's the fix. Put `chart_Series` twice in the function, when `addAdx` is TRUE and FALSE.

```
myPlot = function(ts, addAdx = TRUE) {
if (addAdx) {
  chart_Series(ts)
  add_TA(ADX(HLC(ts))$ADX)
  } else {
  chart_Series(ts)
  }

}

getSymbols("DIA", src='yahoo');
myPlot(DIA, addAdx = FALSE)
```

[image]

```
myPlot(DIA, addAdx = TRUE)
```

[image]